# Same query different database different result

Tags: mysql, postgresql, group-by

I try to change database from 'MySQL' to 'PostgreSQL' but i have problem some of my query

```
SELECT
    SUM( CASE WHEN b.DISPLAYNAME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS NUMMENUDETAIL,
    A.DISPLAYNAME AS GROUPNAME,
    b.displayname,
    D.NAME,
    min( A.ROLEID ) AS ROLEID 
FROM
    usermenu A
    LEFT JOIN usermenu B ON A.ID = B.GROUPID,
    userrole C,
    position D,
    positiondetail E 
WHERE
    ( A.GROUPID IS NULL ) 
    AND D.id = E.position_id 
    AND A.ROLEID = E.userrole_id 
    AND A.ROLEID = C.ID 
    AND B.ROLEID = E.userrole_id 
    AND B.ROLEID = C.ID 
    AND b.displayname = 'Transaction Listing Report' 
GROUP BY
    A.DISPLAYNAME,
    b.displayname 
    LIMIT 10
```

i use this query into "MySQL" it pass
but when i use in "PostgreSQL" it error, They want my to GROUP BY d.name
then if i GROUP BY it may have different result
How can i fix this ?

Comment: Another reason i don't want to group by d.name because i want to list all of different data in d.name by group with displayname

Comment: Formally your query is synthactically wrong. MySQL executes it due to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL Mode is disabled. Add `D.NAME` into GROUP BY expression. And change all comma-style joins to CROSS JOIN, or INNER JOIN with according joining expressions. PS. Your LEFT JOIN is by fact INNER JOIN.

Comment: MySQL's query is wrong as well, but they choose to return random results rather than complaining about the incorrect GROUP BY usage.

Comment: I am surprised that postgresql allows you to mix comma joins and explicit joins like that.

Comment: @Akina Thank you very much, I'll try that

Comment: @P.Salmon Normally it can't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query does not comply with the SQL standard, so it is unsurprising that it does not work on all databases. The standard requires that all columns in the `SELECT` list that do not appear only inside aggregate functions must be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

You can have the same effect by using the (again, non-standard) `DISTINCT ON` clause in PostgreSQL.